# Are two different instances merging?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am having a form which is used to either create/ edit new Departments. I have a functional requirement to unhide few fields after few fields are filled with data.

When I open two Departments to edit, one department has the first set of fields unfilled and hence it hides the second set of fields.

In the second Department which has first set of fields filled, I can see (visible) the second set of fields (which is the way it is coded). But now if I go back to the first Department(already opened in another tab)(open the tab, we coded to refresh the tab on focus), which initially was not filled with the required details, I see that the second set of fields are enabled (of course the filed are yet unfilled).

I am sure that they have different transactions and also different instances but unable to understand this behavior, any idea on how to debug this?

Comment: What do you call a tab? Browser tab or UI shell tab?

Comment: Open a UI shell tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same VO for the same AM/DC then yes, they are sharing the same data (VO Rowset and Binding integrator) so changes to one will be reflected dint he other.
If I understand your problem correctly, one solution would be to create separate Task Flows, one for each Page and then [convert the Bounded taksflows with page fragments](http://oracle-adf.org/Learn_Oracle_ADF/Oracle_11g_ADF_University/Oracle_11g_ADF_I/17Reusability/text27.html). and [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows.htm). Then drop these task flows (as [Regions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows_regions.htm#ADFFD1695)) onto the respective tables. Make sure to mark the task flow as [Always Use New Transaction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adf-task-flow-trans-fund-v1-1-1864319.pdf) and [here](http://suneesh-adf.blogspot.com/2013/10/adf-taskflow-transaction-basics.html) and Data Control Scope/Frame as [Isolated](http://suneesh-adf.blogspot.com/2013/09/sharing-data-control-between-task-flows.html) and [here](http://kristipati.blogspot.com/2011/03/what-is-adf-view-port-data-control.html). If the two task flows need to communicate with each other use a contextual event [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adf-region-interaction/adf-region-interaction.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/AdfInsiderContextualEvents/AdfInsiderContextualEvents.html).